# How to get value in array in asp.net ( or asp-classic would be better)

Tags: javascript, php, asp.net, arrays, asp-classic

I need to get data in javascript array using asp. How to get data and put it in this format in javascript array . This example is of php .

```
<script>var chartdata=[{"values":[<?php $conn =mysql_connect("host","root","pass") or die ("we couldn't connect!");mysql_select_db("test");$rs = mysql_query("SELECT x1 FROM table") or die(mysql_error());while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){echo $row['x'].',';}?>],}];</script>
```

Comment: This has been covered a few times [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33842210/asp-array-to-javascript-array/33869447#33869447).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you know about adodb connection and recordset objects (if you don't there are plenty of tutorials out there), and that you've created one of each called `conn` and `rs`.

In Classic ASP I'd do something like this

```
<% Dim myarraystring, sql
sql = "SELECT x1 FROM table"
myarraystring = ""
rs.open sql,conn
Do While Not rs.eof
myarraystring = myarraystring & rs("x") & ","
rs.movenext
Loop
rs.close %>

<script>var chartdata=[{"values":[<%= myarraystring %>],}];</script>
```

Your connection string would depend on what driver you're using. There's a good resource here for connecting to MySQL with classic asp
http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: Thanks! it taught me new things